# afraid of the cold?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Is it natural to say people living in the tropical countries are typically "afraid of the cold," meaning they are not used to cold weather and find it uncomfortable?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I wouldn't use "afraid". Being uncomfortable does not mean one is afraid of whatever it is that is making them uncomfortable. Can you provide us with a full example sentence.

Comment: Some people tend to wear ridiculously heavy clothes in winter. Would you say they are "afraid of the cold"? If not, how would you describe them?

Comment: I wouldn't use "afraid". If some people wear ridiculously heavy clothes in winter, then chances are they did not grow up there. In this case, I would use the term ["acclimatize"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acclimatize) or simply "they are just not used to this cold weather yet".

Comment: When would you use "afraid of the cold"? I see quite a few examples on Google; I also see "fear the cold."

Comment: I would use "afraid" when it's only a -2 outside and I won't go out because I am terrified the cold will somehow harm me (even though it is only a -2 which is nothing). This is an example. Unless the weather is extreme (say like a hurricane or something), I wouldn't use "afraid".

Comment: Being _afraid of the cold_ has a proper medical name, it’s called Frigophobia. http://www.thecontentwolf.com/life/fear-of-the-cold-frigophobia-is-a-real-thing/

Comment: You could say they are _sensitive to the cold_.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word *unacclimatised* (British English spelling) or *unacclimated* to describe someone who has not yet *adapted* to living in a different climate.

"Afraid" does not seem appropriate - fears can be *irrational* and without basis, so this might suggest that a person "afraid" of the cold has never actually experienced it.

Comment: What about "fear the cold"?